# Application.EnableEvents = true every time returns false

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have opened my excel sheet and then opend the VBA editor.In the immediate window I execute the following command.

```
?Application.EnableEvents = True
```

It returns False .
But If I opened new excel sheet and type the command it returns True. Any reason for that

Comment: have you switched the events off anywhere in your macro code?

Comment: At the workbook close event I diable the events
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Comment: What about `Workbook_open`? What code do you have there? Or do you have an `Auto_Open` code in a module?

Comment: No code in Workbook_open

Comment: Why not just `?Application.EnableEvents`? Drop the `= True`. It contributes nothing.

Comment: Assignment True for Application.EnableEvents,why it returns False?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the command is doing what you think it is.

Remember that VBA overloads the = operator to be both assignment and comparison, and uses context to decide which is which.

The ? Operator makes VBA believe that you're asking "are these two the same", rather than "set this to that".

Some example code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
? Application.EnableEvents
False
? Application.EnableEvents = True
False
? Application.EnableEvents = False
True
? Application.EnableEvents
True
Application.EnableEvents = True
? Application.EnableEvents
True
? Application.EnableEvents = True
True
? Application.EnableEvents = False
False
? Application.Enableevents
True
```

Note that none of the ? commands change the value - all of them merely report whether the *comparison* is true or not, without adjusting the variable. Only a flat assignment will do it.